# Why does the update() statement occur before anything is updated?

Tags: database, velocity

I'm reading [this sample page](http://velocitydb.com/Samples.aspx) on velocitydb, and was wondering about these lines:

```
public Person BestFriend
{
     set
     {
         Update();
         bestFriend = value;
     }
}
```

Why is Update() called before bestFriend is set to the incoming value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update "Marks an object as being updated so that object will be written at commit transaction."